# Python: Simple Dictionary referencing Problem

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a simple problem that i cannot solve. I have a dictionary:

```
aa = {'ALA':'A'}
test = 'ALA'
```

I'm have trouble writing code where that value from test is taken and referenced in the dictionary aa and 'A' is printed.

I'm assuming i would have to use a for loop? something like...

```
for i in test:
    if i in aa:
        print i
```

I understrand how to referenced a dictionary:

```
aa['ALA']
```

Its taking the value from i and using it to reference aa i am having trouble with.

Thanks

James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do, but perhaps you mean:

```
aa = {'ALA':'A'}
test = ['ALA']  ### note this is now a list!

for i in test:
    if i in aa:
        print i, aa[i]  #### note i is the key, aa[i] is the value
```

note that you can make three different kinds of iterators from a dictionary:

```
aa.iteritems()   # tuples of (key, value)
                 # ('ALA', 'A')
aa.iterkeys()    # keys only -- equivalent to just making an iterator directly from aa
                 # 'ALA'
aa.itervalues()  # items only
                 # 'A'
```

Answer (score 2):

> I'm have trouble writing code where that value from test is taken and referenced in the dictionary aa and 'A' is printed.

Do you mean this?

```
print aa[test]
```

> Its taking the value from i and using it to reference aa i am having trouble with.

I don’t exactly understand why you’re *iterating over* the characters in the string variable `test`. Is this really what you want? The rest of your question suggests that it’s not.

Comment: I'm planning on using this on a larger dictionary, were multiple values are taken, referenced into a dictionary and printed.
I didnt intend to interate over the character, i understand now that i did.